# Как создать категорию через Discord.js?

Tags: бот, discord

Как создать категорию через Discord.js?

- Пробовал через .createChannel ,но выдавала ошибку.
- TypeError: channelType.toUpperCase is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```js
guild.channels.create('<название>', {type: 'category'})
```

Answer (score -2):

Чтобы создать категорию надо прописать.

```
message.guild.createChannel("название","category")
```